# Why am I having to set the dataType to text?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery

I have the following script which works, but I don't understand why it will not work when the type is set to json:

**Serverside:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain" '//#### <- should't this be text/json? ###
    Response.Write(getTabFrame())
    Response.End()
End Sub

Function getTabFrame() As String
    objStringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    objStringBuilder.Append("[")

    objStringBuilder.Append("{""key"":1,""value"":""Default""},")
    objStringBuilder.Append("{""key"":2,""value"":""Reports""},")
    objStringBuilder.Append("{""key"":3,""value"":""Other""}")

    objStringBuilder.Append("]")

    Return objStringBuilder.ToString
End Function
```

**Clientside:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'serverside',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text', //#### <------------------------ shouldn't this be json? ###
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error + '\nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(results) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
        var len = obj.length; 

        for(i=0; i<len; i++) { 
            $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + obj[i].key, obj[i].value)
        };
    }
});
```

When I change those values to json, the whole thing stops working and returns "null"...

Why?

Comment: Can you post a sample response? And you don't have to `parseJSON()`, jQuery does it for you when you specify the `dataType` of `json`.

Comment: Did you try `application/json`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: to expand on @no.good's query, add a `console.log(results);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `dataType` is `json`, you don't need to do `parseJSON` on `results` - it will already be a javascript object literal.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Response.ContentType = "application/json";` on server side, and in AJAX call use

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be an appropriate to use 
• Response.ContentType = "text/html";

The XML validates and checks the markup validity of Web documents in HTML, XHTML, SMIL, MathML, etc. to conform to w3 standards.

SAMPLE CODE: (With error)
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/json";  //#### <- should't this be ‘application/json’?
    Response.Write(getTabFrame());
    Response.End();
}

private string  getTabFrame()
{
    var objStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    objStringBuilder.Append("[");
    objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":1,\"value\":\"Default\"},");
    objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":2,\"value\":\"Reports\"},") ;
    objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":3,\"value\":\"Other\"}");
    objStringBuilder.Append("]");
    return objStringBuilder.ToString();
}

Page Error Output:

The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'http://localhost:1713/Default.aspx'. Line 1, Position...

[{"key":1,"value":"Default"},{"key":2,"value":"Reports"},{"key":3,"value":"Other"}]
^

SAMPLE CODE: (No error)
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";  //#### <- should't this be text/html? ###
    Response.Write(getTabFrame());
    Response.End();
}

private string  getTabFrame()
{
   var objStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   objStringBuilder.Append("[");
   objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":1,\"value\":\"Default\"},");
   objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":2,\"value\":\"Reports\"},") ;
   objStringBuilder.Append("{\"key\":3,\"value\":\"Other\"}");
   objStringBuilder.Append("]");
   return objStringBuilder.ToString();
}

Page Output(No error):

[{"key":1,"value":"Default"},{"key":2,"value":"Reports"},{"key":3,"value":"Other"}]